# Creating 3D terrain from DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis

We have a piece of land in Grand Lake, CO.  We want to build a house on it but the land is on a slope so we need to have a 3D terrain map to locate the house at the optimal location.  I’m mainly going off this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZZ2MVLZN4o but it doesn’t work for me.

I start by making a line string in Google Earth, like this:

[image]

Then I save it as .kml file and import that file into GPS Visualizer.  That gets all the elevations along the line.  Then I *Convert & add elevation* as a plain text file and save the file.

Then in QGIS version 3.28.14-Firenze, I select *Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer*.  In the popup window, I open the text file and the data gets imported.  The Sample Data looks good.  I select *X field as LONG, Y field as LAT, and Z field as ALT*.  I leave all the other fields at their defaults and click the *Add* button.  All the points come in as shown:

[image]

Next, I create the DEM by double-clicking the *Interpolation > IDW interpolation* in the Processing Toolbox.  In the popup dialog, I click the plus button to add a layer and set its *Type* to *Structure lines*.  I set the *Extent to Calculate from Layer >* [name of elevation points].  I set the *Rows* to 100, leave the rest at their defaults, and click the *Run* button.  After about 5 seconds it creates a DEM as shown:

[image]

Next, I select *Basemaps > Google Satellite* from the *HCMGIS* plugin, It loads the image, overlayed on the DEM correctly:

[image]

Finally, I click the green tent icon in the in the *Qgis2threejs Exporter* plugin.

Instead of a nice 3D terrain as shown in the video, I get a wonky image like this:

[image]

I’ve been to create a 3D terrain model.

Can anybody tell me what I’m doing wrong, or recommend a workflow that actually works?

I do not seek methods that require commercial software such as ArcMap, Rhino, Civil 3D, Autocad, etc.

Comment: What does it look like if you use a proper local CRS for your project/map?

Comment: Are there no ready made DEM available for you in your area? Or why not use Google Earth which has a 3D topography view? And: in your last screenshot, when you zoom to the top of the "tower", don't you see the topography there? And what about QGIS native 3D view?